# Como colocar dos tamaños a una sentencia de imagettftext en GD PHP

Tags: php, php7, gd

He estado usando la libreria GD de PHP para generar unos certificados digitales.

Para eso cree  varias funciones , para que, ademas de generarlo, me centrara el titular mas DNI en el medio del certificado, pero el DNI debe estar en un tamaño de fuente menor que es 36, mientras que el tiular en 72, entonces mi pregunta es como lo hago todo en la misma sentencia o habra alguna forma de hacer lo que necesito?

Este es mi codigo hasta ahora:

```
<?php

function textSize($size, $angle, $font, $text) {
    $f = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);
    return array(
        'height' => $f[1] - $f[5],
        'width' => $f[4] - $f[0]
    );
}

function text(&$im, $size, $angle, $y, $color, $font, $text, $align) {
    // Image/text sizes
    $imageSize = array(
        'height' => imagesy($im),
        'width' => imagesx($im)
    );
    $textSize = textSize($size, $angle, $font, $text);
    // Starting $x position
    switch(strtoupper($align)) {
        case 'R':
            $x = $imageSize['width'] - $textSize['width'];
            break;
        case 'C':
      $x = ($imageSize['width'] - $textSize['width']) / 2;
            break;
        default:
            $x = 0; // L
    }
    // Render
    imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $color, $font, $text);
    return $x;
}

function CreateImg($valornombres,$valorapellidos,$valordni,$horas_totales,$dia_final,$mes,$ano)
{    
     $image_path = 'images/7x2_certificado_en_blanco.jpg';
     $image_to = 'images/7x2_certificado_en_blanco_modificed.jpg';
     $font_path_arial = '/rsc/arial.ttf';
     $font_path_arial_bold = '/rsc/arial_bold.ttf';
     $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
     $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $textnombres = $valornombres;
    $textapellidos = $valorapellidos;
    $textdni = $valordni;
    $titular = $textnombres.' '.$textapellidos;
    $bbox = imagettfbbox(72, 0, $font_path_arial, $titular);
    imagettftext($im, 48, 0, (text($im, 72, 0, 1035, $black, $font_path_arial_bold, $titular, 'c') + $bbox[4]+50), 1035, $black, $font_path_arial,' DNI:'.$valordni);
      imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 1095, 1490, $black, $font_path_arial,$horas_totales);
      imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 1965, 1490, $black, $font_path_arial,$dia_final);
      imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 2200, 1490, $black, $font_path_arial,$mes);
      imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 2495, 1490, $black, $font_path_arial,$ano);
     imagejpeg($im,$image_to);
     if(imagejpeg($im,$image_to)){
          imagedestroy($im);
          return $image_to;
     } else {
          echo('error');
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Es mejor que uses clases CSS. Así, a cada contenido le das una clase y luego agregas un archivo de estilos donde manejas los tamaños, colores, márgenes o lo que quieras. Así, si creas por ejemplo dos contenedores: `<div class="titulo">Contenido del título</di>` y `<div class="detalle">Contenido del detalle: texto, imágenes, etc</div>` y el CSS pones algo así: `,titulo { */reglas*/ }` y `.detalle { /*reglas*/ }´ aplicarías entre los `{ }` todos los estilos y listo. Otra ventaja de esto es que cuando quieras cambiar algo sólo lo cambias en el CSS y no tienes que modificar el HTML.

Comment: bro, pero dentro de la biblioteca de gd, interpreta html?

Comment: No tiene nada que ver. Supongo que la imagen que muestras tiene contenido HTML ¿no? Entonces, si generas el contenido desde PHP poniéndole clases y luego agregas un archivo de estilos, te dará el formato que indiques en casa clase. Es así como se trabaja hoy día, separando lo que es el contenido por un lado PHP/HTML y los formatos y estilos por otro (tamaños, colores, márgenes, etc) con CSS.

Comment: me explico, estoy procesando unas imagenes, osea editando un formato en jpg, que es la plantilla del certificado en jpg, y le estoy agregando textos, estos texto vienen de un formulario. entonces vuelvo a realizar la pregunta
 ¿en la función imagettftext cuando pego por ejemplo $valordni, alli inserto un string con contenido html y eso lo interpretará?

Comment: Espera un momento. O sea, ¿me estas diciendo que lo que muestras en la pregunta es una imagen todo ello, incluyendo el texto? Es que no entendí esa parte. Si es todo una imagen, ¿eso es para imprimirlo o es para mostrarlo en una web?

Comment: es para posteriormente imprimirlo, por que osea esos son unos template vacio verdad pero manualmente yo debo estar editando los datos, posicionandolo etc, entonces estoy intentando programar un especie de generador donde nada mas colocar los datos me posicione los texto y guardo la imagen.
aqui subi lo que tengo https://kiwilab.dev/rossy/index.php

mi problema es que en la sentencia del titular el titular debe tener 72 de tamaño y en donde va el DNI 36, pero debo colocarlo en una sentencia para que se centre en conjunto con el titular

Comment: Ok. Realmente no conozco esa librería, estuve mirando en el Manual de PHP y ufff me parece algo de siglo pasado. Es posible que se pueda hacer lo que quieras, pero pasando por un procedimiento complicado. Yo me pregunto, por qué mejor no modernizas, simplificas el código, generando por ejemplo un PDF o algo así.